# How do I iterate over a Python dictionary, ordered by values?

Tags: python

I've got a dictionary like:

```
{ 'a': 6, 'b': 1, 'c': 2 }
```

I'd like to iterate over it *by value*, not by key. In other words:

```
(b, 1)
(c, 2)
(a, 6)
```

What's the most straightforward way?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-dictionary-in-python-by-the-value

Comment: Not a dupe. The other one wants to sort a dictionary, which is impossible. I want to iterate over a dictionary in a sorted order.

Comment: and the code is exactly the same.

Comment: Since you can't sort a dictionary, the code **must** be the same.  Duplicate.

Comment: The answers are the same, but the questions are different. I found the other one before I posted this, read the question, and said, "No, this isn't what I'm asking". That's why I posted this.

Comment: @Mike: and what difference do you see between that question and yours?

Comment: That question is asking how to do something impossible: sort a dictionary. Dictionaries can't be sorted. I'm asking how to do something possible: iterate over a dictionary in sorted order. Dictionaries *can* be iterated over in sorted order.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

for these of you that hate lambda :-)

```
import operator
sorted(dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

However `operator` version requires CPython 2.5+

Comment: I need the keys and the items, not just the items.

Comment: dictionary.items() gives you both the keys and values, not just the keys.

Comment: @Mike: items are (key, value) pairs.

Comment: ..or `key = operator.itemgetter(1)`.

Answer (score 7):

For non-Python 3 programs, you'll want to use iteritems to get the performance boost of generators, which yield values one at a time instead of returning all of them at once.

```
sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

For even larger dictionaries, we can go a step further and have the key function [be in C](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Modules/operator.c) instead of Python as it is right now with the lambda.

```
import operator
sorted(d.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Hooray!

Comment: Oooh. Nice with the operator.itemgetter. Sweet.

Comment: Though I haven't tested, I'm sceptical about the claim that `sorted` performs better on a consumable iterator than a list. I'd guess that the very first thing `sorted` does is read that iterator into a list anyway; it's very unclear whether there's a performance gain to be had, here.

Answer (score 5):

It can often be very handy to use **[namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)**. For example, you have a dictionary of name and score and you want to sort on 'score':

```
import collections
Player = collections.namedtuple('Player', 'score name')
d = {'John':5, 'Alex':10, 'Richard': 7}
```

sorting with lowest score first:

```
worst = sorted(Player(v,k) for (k,v) in d.items())
```

sorting with highest score first:

```
best = sorted([Player(v,k) for (k,v) in d.items()], reverse=True)
```

The order of 'key' and 'value' in the listed tuples is (value, key), but now you can get the name and score of, let's say the second-best player (index=1) very Pythonically like this:

```
    player = best[1]
    player.name
        'Richard'
    player.score
         7
```

Answer (score 3):

The `items` method gives you a list of (key,value) tuples, which can be sorted using `sorted` and a custom sort key:

```
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Jan 13 2009, 10:26:13) 

>>> a={ 'a': 6, 'b': 1, 'c': 2 }
>>> sorted(a.items(), key=lambda (key,value): value)
[('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 6)]
```

In Python 3, the lambda expression will have to be changed to `lambda x: x[1]`.

Comment: You might want to remove the first three lines and the last one...looks a little busy right now.

Comment: Note that tuple unpacking is no longer supported in Python 3... unfortunately.

Comment: @Nikhil I think the header is important. Especially per @Stephan's comment, it's significant which version I'm using for the demo.

Comment: @Barry: isn't it clear from your syntax what version are you using?