# How to iterate through keys of a dictionary which is sorted with values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to iterate through the keys of a dictionary which is sorted with values. one method is to use ordered dictionary means initialize dictionary with sorted values.

code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict([('a',0), ('d',1), ('c',2), ('b',3)])

for mykey in data:
    print mykey
```

How can i achieve this without using Ordered dictionary ?
I know that above was correct method to achieve this, i just want to know can we do the same without using Ordered dictionary.

```
sorted(dictionary.values)
```

will give me only sorted list of values not whole dictionary with sorted values so i can't have keys here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over a Python dictionary, ordered by values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674509/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-python-dictionary-ordered-by-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dict.iteritems` to get list of tuples from dict and sort it with `sorted`:

```
sorted(dictionary.iteritems(), key=lambda i: i[1])
```

from python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) about key argument:

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default
>   value is None (compare the elements directly).

Comment: for mykey in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]): print mykey       //its printing tuples, i want to print key

Comment: @Patrick change it to: `for key, value in sorted(...): print key`

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320202/355230) to another question to obtain a relatively simple, yet fast, implementation, as shown:

```
class ValueOrderedDict(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}
        self.L = []
        self.sorted = True
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.d[k]
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        if k not in self.d:
            self.L.append((v, k))
            self.sorted = False
        self.d[k] = v
    def __delitem__(self, k):
        v = self.d[k]
        del self.d[k]
        self.L.remove((v, k))
    def __iter__(self):
       if not self.sorted:
           self.L.sort()
           self.sorted = True
       for v, k in self.L:
           yield k

vod = ValueOrderedDict()
vod['a'] = 10
vod['b'] =  5
vod['c'] = 20

for k in vod:
    print 'vod[{!r}]: {}'.format(k, vod[k])
```

Output:

```
vod['b']: 5
vod['a']: 10
vod['c']: 20
```